# React sending async state from parent to child component after fetch in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state, use-effect, rerender

I'm trying to send async state value from parent to child after setting state of a data coming from fetch API:

**Profile.js**

```
function Profile() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/users/${id}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setUser(data);
    };

    getUser();
  }, [id]);


   return (
    ...

    <Feed id={user._id} />

    ...
  )
}
```

**Feed.js**

```
function Feed(id) {

  const { user, isLoading, error } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      const response = id
        ? await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/${id}`)
        : await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/home/${user._id}`);

      const data = await response.json();
      setPosts(data);
    };

    getPosts();
  }, [id, userId, user._id]);

  ...
}
```

on **Profile.js** component i solved the issue by using the optional chaining operator **?**

```
  <div className={profileStyles.userItem}>
    phone: <span>{user?.phone}</span>
  </div>
```

but i dont know how to tell the **Feed.js** component to wait for **id** prop, so it will be null and the **Feed.js** component will not re-render, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wait for the user to be fetched, you can render `Feed` only when the user is not undefined (so it waits that it is fetched):

```
{user && <Feed id={user._id} />
```

This way, the component `Feed` will be rendered only when the user is not undefined

Comment: but i dont want the ***Feed*** component to be only rendered when the user is not undefined, if you check the ***Feed*** component Im using conditional fetching

Comment: ahh ok i got that, i will try it

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve here, with this conditional fetching. What is your issue exactly?

Comment: the conditional fetching here decide if there is id it means feed for user profile, else then its feed for timeline, i used your solution and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'm glad that I could help! However, now , the first condition of this conditional fetching will always be true, since you render Feed only when the user is fetched (I don't know if it is what you wanted to do?)

Comment: yep, exactly, i should only render the feed component in the profile component when user data is there, and i will do the same for other component which also use the feed component to achieve the second fetch condition

Comment: Ok perfect then!